# What is the easiest way to convert the timeseries of a Dataframe from UTC-6 to UTC?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to change the timezone of of a time serie from UTC-6 to UTC. 
I imported the data from a `.csv` file:

```
dt = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

and then I set the `Datetime` as indexes

```
dt.index = pd.to_datetime(dt.pop('Datetime'))
dt.head()
                       Raw  Raw_filtered
Datetime                                 
2015-01-09 11:50:00   620.0         620.0
2015-01-09 12:00:00   610.0         610.0
2015-01-09 12:10:00   700.0         700.0
2015-01-09 12:20:00  1330.0        1330.0
2015-01-09 12:30:00  1800.0        1800.0
```

I would like to change the Datetime column to UTC, what is a simple way of doing that?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what timezone they're in right now?

Comment: Is it *always* UTC-6, or is there daylight saving time involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [181]: df
Out[181]:
             Datetime     Raw  Raw_filtered
0 2015-01-09 11:50:00   620.0         620.0
1 2015-01-09 12:00:00   610.0         610.0
2 2015-01-09 12:10:00   700.0         700.0
3 2015-01-09 12:20:00  1330.0        1330.0
4 2015-01-09 12:30:00  1800.0        1800.0

In [182]: df.Datetime.dt.tz_localize('US/Central').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
Out[182]:
0   2015-01-09 17:50:00+00:00
1   2015-01-09 18:00:00+00:00
2   2015-01-09 18:10:00+00:00
3   2015-01-09 18:20:00+00:00
4   2015-01-09 18:30:00+00:00
Name: Datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Comment: If the timezone is truly `UTC-6` this will be wrong, because it includes daylight saving time.

Comment: @MarkRansom, AFAIK there is no such thing as `UTC-6`, there is `GMT-6`... i could be wrong though...

Comment: Thanks it works! Yes, it doesn't exist `UTC-6`, my bad.

Comment: According to pytz.all_timezones, you want `tz_localize('Etc/GMT-6')`. (There is no difference between GMT and UTC.)

Comment: @olooney, this looks good, thank you! But it gives me different result set. For instance `05:50:00+00:00` instead of `17:50:00+00:00`...

Comment: @MaxU good catch. Apparently POSIX dictates that the sign convention for the "Etc/GMT" timezones are [reversed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area) relative to ISO-8601. So it would be "Etc/GMT+6".

Answer (score 0):

If you are definitely sure that the `DataTime` in your data is `UTC-6`, you could add it with a proper `pd.Timedelta` as the compensation to be `UTC`. For example:

```
dt.index = dt.index + pd.Timedelta('6 hours')
```

Hope this would be helpful.